# Nose skip debug messages

Tags: python, selenium, testing, nose

I starts nosetests with selenium as

```
python my_test.py  --tests=my_test --with-xunit  --xunit-file=my_output.xml
```

and I get a lot of useless output like:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:42919/session/23784289y34ui2hi2u3hi2u/elements {"using": "xpath", "sessionId": "23784289y34ui2hi2u3hi2u", "value": "//span[@class='somename']"}
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: Finished Request
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:22919/session/2i3ur2oirhi2u3hri2uhri/element/0.37232323248244116-1/click {"sessionId": "2i3ur2oirhi2u3hri2uhri", "id": "0.37232323248244116-1"}
```

How can I skip all these debug messages and gets only messages about errors?
I did tried with `--logging-level=Error` or `Default` but it does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the selenium. I added a couple lines of code and this fixed the problem.

```
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING) # this line should be before webdriver initialization
```